# Jquery Doesn't work On Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, syntax, rubygems

I am having trouble using jquery on rails.In my comments.js file i add

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require cocoon
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

$( document ).ready(function() {
  alert("This javascripts thing is reals making me mad!");
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#comments_link").click(function(){
        $(".comments-section").toggle();
    });                             
})
```

In my application.html.haml i have;

```
  = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true 
  = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true 
  = csrf_meta_tags
```

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!UPDATE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
It got solved by adding preventDefault.Final version is below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".harun").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("section").toggle();
});
```

})

Comment: should not use `$(document).on("ready"....` it is deprecated http://api.jquery.com/ready/. Doubt that will solve error but try moving code inside that to just after `alert()` and removing it

Comment: i tried the normal $(document).ready way. It doesn't work either.I should change it to normal up there.Thanks for showing it.

Comment: jQuery code shown is syntactically correct. What does generated source look like in browser

Comment: Well, since i am a newbie. i think you saying "inspect element".If true it says " Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token".On console i did $(".comments_section").show() and now i am even more confused why is doesn't working on page.

Comment: I'm saying look at the actual code that rails sends to browser. Try View Source in browser....or open browser dev tools and explore (F12)

Comment: ıt says "comments.self-8582264a50ba47920e1347e1214bac59f070e6b237a78ce24f42f8f5650218bc.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

Comment: That's the error message, not the generated source code that browser is using that generates that error

Comment: It is weird.I tried something random to see if syntax is wrong.I pick the image as click event listener and  picked both ".comments_section" and "#comments_link" as toggle element.Both way it works but when it comes to  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#comments_link").click(function(){
        $(".comments-section").toggle();
    });                             
}) it doesn't.Whyyyy?

Comment: no idea and I'm not  very rails literate which is why i wonder what is actually being sent from server to browser and that needs to be determined in browser

Comment: well when i press f12 i got the same screen  as inspecting the element.And the source panel is showing nothing but error message.But i realized it is  not  working only if i pick the "#comments_link" as event listener.Every other element works but the this one.So weird

Answer (score 0):

This is the same underlying problem you had over in your other question: [Can't select link_to tag as jquery selector Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38465998/152786)

You're using `turbolinks` which does not fire the `$(document).ready` event on page transition.  Copying from the turbolinks docs: [Running JavaScript When a Page Loads](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#running-javascript-when-a-page-loads)

> You may be used to installing JavaScript behavior in response to the `window.onload`, `DOMContentLoaded`, or jQuery `ready` events. With Turbolinks, these events will fire only in response to the initial page load—not after any subsequent page changes.
>
> In many cases, you can simply adjust your code to listen for the `turbolinks:load` event, which fires once on the initial page load and again after every Turbolinks visit.
>
> ```
> document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
>   // ...
> })
> ```