# Can't select link_to tag as jquery selector Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml

I am a beginner rails dev. I got this link_to tag with the class of "comments_link"

```
%h2= link_to pluralize(@recipe.comments.count, "Comment"), "#", class: "comments_link , btn btn-success"
```

Now, in **application.js** i wrote

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".comments_link").click(function(){
    $(".section").toggle();
  });                               
})
```

The problem with this code, whatever element i choose for click event, it works. But when i use `.comments_link` class, it doesn't work. Why is this happening?

Anything but `link_to` tags work as event listener. Do i need to add some sort of code to it?

Btw i did the reverse just to try and it worked. When i click on the section, it toggles the link. But the link cant be event listener.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".section").click(function(){
    $(".comments_link").toggle();
  });                               
}); <-- this one worked. I cant use ".comments_link" as event listener.
```

Comment: You have a ',' inside your class.

Comment: I deleted the " , btn btn-default" part just to be sure.Yet didn't work.

Comment: I'd like to see the generated html.

Comment: <a href="#">Toggle</a>

Comment: The link you're showing the haml for should have the text "Comment" or "Comments" - try again.

Comment: This could well be a turbolinks related problem.  @HarunTuncay, does the click work after reloading the page?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".comments_link").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".section").toggle();
  });                               
}) ----> Preventing the default solved it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a comma in the class name which I assume would invalidate the class name. Check developer tools in order to inspect the element to see if `.comment_link` actually exists. If not, remove the comma and try again

Comment: nope.comma didn't effect it either.this is one weird error.

Comment: So you have verified the class name is correct on the element?

Comment: The issue seems to be with the HTML. Can you post the HTML output

Comment: Html or the page doesn't change at all.It refreshes the page, i guess makes a request but doesn't do anything in return.Also when i press F12 and then click on the link, source doesn't change at all.

Comment: I meant just show the HTML that is generated on page load

Comment: <a href="#">Toggle</a>

Comment: That shows no class name and the word `Toggle` does not appear in the code within your question. Please update the question with the relevant HTML output

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".comments_link").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".section").toggle();
  });                               
})  This solve the problem

Answer (score -1):

Assuming this is a problem with turbolinks, you can fix this by preventing the default action on the click in your event handler (which is a good idea anyway):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".comments_link").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".section").toggle();
  });                               
})
```

Comment: Thank you.Finally got solved! But will i need to do it everytime i add jquery to a link or is there a more specific way? Thank you again!

Comment: If you want the link to NOT act like a link then this is a good idea.  You _can_ do this for all links, eg. all links with `"#"` as the href, like `$("a[href='#']").click( function(e) { e.preventDefault() })` - but I think it's better to be explicit and have that in each event handler.

Comment: Okay.Thank again.You are a time saver :)

Comment: Don't forget to accept/vote - there were a lot of good efforts here to help you.

Comment: Love the downvote action, even though @HarunTuncay commented that this was the fix. Trolololol